# tensorflow Attempting to use uninitialized value W in a class

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

As my question,I define a class.In **init**, I new some tf value.And init global,init local.Even in main script.

```
class DNN():
    def __init__(self):
        kernel_shape = [3,3]
        self.c11w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(kernel_shape + [3, 64], stddev=0.1), name = 'W'))
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
```

Like this.And uninitiated error.So I call tf.report_uninitialized_variables(), just empty.

So,I want to know why and how, thanks much.

Comment: Sorry, this is impossible to answer. Where is `W`?

Comment: W was a tf value, defined in init

Comment: Except it's not defined in init. Otherwise it would be in your code

Comment: Sorry, I thought how to define it was doesnt matter. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

In TF, variables values live in session only. Once session is closed there are no values anymore, thus in your current code you create variables, initialise them, and then discard them, all in the constructor.

Typical pattern for integrating TF to OO code in python would be something among the lines of:

```
class MLobject():
  def __init__(self):
    self._graph = tf.Graph() # separate graph per instance
    with self._graph.as_default():
      variable_1 = ....
      ...
      self._initialiser = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    self._session = tf.Session(graph=self._graph) # store session in a field
    self._graph.finalize() # For safety, this should not be modified anymore

  def fit(self, X, y):
    self._session.run(self._initialiser)
    ... # execute training using self._session
```